# How to connect Rails to non-Ruby backends?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have Java backends which I want Rails to communicate with some kind of RPC. How exactly do I set this up and where should the RPC call architecturally go in the rails app, which file and which directory of the rails app, controller or model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easies to use on the Rails side would be some sort of JSON protocol.
If you need to parse SOAP in ruby then you can look at Savon, it parses the xml response into a nice hash.

If you are asking about where to put the code that speaks to the backend and makes the calls then that is usually put in the lib dir. If you need to receive requests, then will be in the controller of course.

Comment: So you say it makes most logical sense to make the rpc request in the controller?

Comment: No, you do the request in the place where you need it, I talked about where to respond to requests.